# SELinux: How to undo/revert semanage permissive -a httpd_t?

Tags: selinux

I temporarily ran this:

```
semanage permissive -a httpd_t
```

To debug a domain process type issue I was having but now I can't seem to undo it.

I attempt to swap "permissive" with "enforcing" but the response was:

```
idiot, RTFM
```

No I'm kidding, the actual response was:

```
usage: semanage [-h]

            {import,export,login,user,port,interface,module,node,fcontext,boolean,permissive,dontaudit}
            ...
semanage: error: argument subcommand: invalid choice: 'enforcing' (choose from 'import', 'export', 'login', 'user', 'port', 'interface', 'module', 'node', 'fcontext', 'boolean', 'permissive', 'dontaudit')
```

So... None of these usage options were what I was expecting. What usage option should I use if I just want whatever is set in /etc/selinux/config to be honored? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would try

```
semanage permissive -d httpd_t
```

as the [idiot fm](https://www.mankier.com/8/semanage-permissive) says

> -d, --delete Delete a record of the specified object type